How can a bot forward messages to a Telegram group
I need to make a bot that should forward messages sent to him in the group. How can this be done, I have searched a lot of information, nothing helps
I tried to forward the group ID, maybe I did something wrong, but when the bot wrote to me that the message had been sent, nothing appeared in the group. (if the bot was an admin in the group and had access to messages)

Are you using BotFather?

In more detail pls

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
